# Strange behaviour with jquery .click() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm trying to doing a simple thing but probably i miss something.
I've this little HTML

```
<div class="open"> OPEN</div>
```

with this simple CSS:

```
.open {
   color: green;
}

.close {
   color: red;
}
```

Now want to catch .click() events on the div but i want to select the  with the class selector.
And for second i need to change the class and catch again a different .click() event based on the  class. So I used this JQuery code:

```
$('.open').click(function() {
  alert('open');
  $(this).removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('close');
  $(this).text('CLOSE');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  alert('close');
  $(this).removeClass('close');
  $(this).addClass('open');
  $(this).text('OPEN');
});
```

But this not work:

- First click: right alert, class change, text change
- Second click: wrong alert, class not change, text not change

You can check this jsfiddle: [JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ezxe9ca8/1/)

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need event delegation for this. since in the beginning, there is no div with the class close, the click handler is assigned to nothing.

just wrap your div
    
       OPEN
    
and assign the click handler to the main div

```
$('.wrapper').on("click", ".open",function() {
  alert('open');
  $(this).removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('close');
  $(this).text('CLOSE');
});

$('.wrapper').on("click", ".close",function() {
  alert('close');
  $(this).removeClass('close');
  $(this).addClass('open');
  $(this).text('OPEN');
});
```

instead of `$(this).removeClass('close'); $(this).addClass('open');` you shout consider to use `$(this).toggleClass('open close');`

https://jsfiddle.net/ezxe9ca8/2/

Comment: yeah it works, but i'd suggest to use Jai's solution, maybe with some little tweaks... i just made your code working, Jai optimised it...

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this with:

```js
$('.open').click(function(){
     var txt = $.trim(this.textContent) == "OPEN" ? "CLOSE" : "OPEN";
    $(this).toggleClass('open').text(txt);
    // $(this).toggleClass('open close').text(txt);
    // use the commented line if you want to toggle the classes on each click.
});
```

```css
.open {
   color: green;
}

.close {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open"> OPEN</div>
```

Comment: do i get you right, you never remove the open class - therefore the click handler is always available - and you just add the close class via toggle - so the div has either class="open" or class="open close", this may bring up new problems, if you have several open/close divs and want to treat them differently ...

Comment: @errand yes this should do. other way is to use `.toggleClass('open close')` this way.

Comment: @errand that's why `$(this)` is used.

Comment: i'm aware of the use of $(this) - but i missed, that, since the click handler is bind to the element in the beginning, seem to be available, even when loosing the .open class...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.general').click(function() {

 var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
 if(status == 'open') {
    alert('open');
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('close');
    $(this).text('CLOSE');
    $(this).attr('data-status', 'close');
 } else if(status == 'close') {
    alert('close');
    $(this).removeClass('close');
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).text('OPEN');
    $(this).attr('data-status', 'open');
 }

});
```

Then apply class to div

```
    <div class="open general" data-status='open'> OPEN</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the event handler bound to HTML element. In this case with the `<div>` No with the class close or open. For this reason, when you click on div only tigger the handler with `alert("opne")`.

The solution is: Use only one handler and inside it put a 'if' stament. In pseudocode:

```
if class open
 do someting
else if class close
 do someting
```